# Averaging multiple UIImages

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, average, blending

I have been searching for this answer for a while. But I haven't been able to find it.

I would like to average the pixels of 30 UIimages. To do so, I would like to do it using Quartz2D instead of going over all the pixels of all the images. It ocurred to me that, in order to paint 30 images together I should just adjust the alpha channel of each of them to 1/30. Then, after painting one in top of the other I would get the desired effect.

the desired formula should be: Dest Px = (img[0].px+....img[29].px)/30

I have tried to achieve it using an imageContext and blending the images together with no luck:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(sz.width, sz.height));

for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {

    UIImage* img = [self.delegate requestImage:self at:i];

    CGPoint coord = [self.delegate requestTranslation:self at:i];

    [img drawAtPoint:coord blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1/30];

}

UIImage* im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

How could I get an averaged image of many UIimages?
I have also tried adding an image with many sublayers, but I also get washed out images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the following:

```
[img drawAtPoint:coord blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1/30];
```

to

```
[img drawAtPoint:coord blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0/30.0];
```

1/30 (using integer values) == 0, so you'll be drawing the images completely transparent. By adding the `.0`, you clarify that you want a `CGFloat`.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. 
I needed an escalated blending: apply alpha 1.0 to the first image, 0.5 to the second, 0.33 to the third and so on. This is because the blending is applied to the background.